# Javascript submenu duplicated

Tags: javascript, html, yui

I'm doing a javascript vertical submenu, I'm using yui tools but the submenu is duplicated, I don't know what part of code is wrong.

```js
YAHOO.util.Event.onContentReady("menu_vertical", function() {
  var elMenu = new YAHOO.widget.Menu("menu_vertical", {
    width: '550px'
  });
  elMenu.render();
  elMenu.show();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.3.0/
    build/menu/assets/skins/sam/menu.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.3.0/build/
    yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.3.0/build/
    container/container_core-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.3.0/build/menu/
    menu-min.js"></script>

<div id="menu_vertical" class="yuimenu">
  <div class="bd">
    <ul class="first-of-type">
      <li class="yuimenuitem"><a href="#">MENU1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="yuimenuitem"><a href="#">MENU2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="yuimenuitem">MENU3
        <div id="consectetuer" class="yuimenu">
          <div class="bd">
            <ul>
              <li class="yuimenuitem"><a href="#">SUBMENU1</a>
              </li>
              <li class="yuimenuitem"><a href="#">SUBMENU2</a>
              </li>
              <li class="yuimenuitem"><a href="#">SUBMENU3 </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="yuimenuitem"><a href="#">MENU4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Please create jsfiddle of this example.

Comment: `elMenu.render();elMenu.show();` Are you sure you need render and show method ?

Comment: im not sure. I'm beginning has to learn javascript. This is an exercise, I've completed following a tutorial

Comment: Doesn't look like all your tags are closed. Also, those scripts are returning an error code.

Comment: I see them closed, where you see the problem tags?

Comment: @Urahara in jsfiddle works, but in my browser no...

Comment: Include a link to your JSFiddle code. Note: Your example HTML code you posted here is missing two closing div tags. If you are going to redact portions of your code, still make sure that it is properly formatted.

Comment: this is code in jsfiddle, here it works but no in my browser https://jsfiddle.net/832t0duL/

Answer (score 0):

In your JSFiddle you linked, your href and src tags have spaces in the path and these link and script tags must not be embedded inside of a script since they are raw HTML. Here is an [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/832t0duL/1/), but you still have issues.

You are attempting to reference plain http over an https connection, this is not safe, and JSFiddle and Stackoverflow will not allow you to do such a thing.

Other than that, your code looks fine. The [Menu Family: Multi-tiered Menu From Markup](http://pbskids.org/includes/javascript/yui/2/2.3.1/examples/menu/example07.html) example that I found using Google may be a good place to check if your code is correct. Here is the [*"clean page"*](http://pbskids.org/includes/javascript/yui/2/2.3.1/examples/menu/example07_clean.html) of that example.

```js
YAHOO.util.Event.onContentReady("menu_vertical", function () {
    var elMenu = new YAHOO.widget.Menu("menu_vertical", {
        width: '550px'
    });
    elMenu.render();
    elMenu.show();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.3.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.3.0/build/container/container_core-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.3.0/build/menu/menu-min.js"></script>

<link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.3.0/build/menu/assets/skins/sam/menu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="menu_vertical" class="yuimenu">
    <div class="bd">
        <ul class="first-of-type">
            <li class="yuimenuitem"><a href="#">MENU1</a></li>
            <li class="yuimenuitem"><a href="#">MENU2</a></li>
            <li class="yuimenuitem">MENU3
                <div id="consectetuer" class="yuimenu">
                    <div class="bd">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="yuimenuitem"><a href="#">SUBMENU1</a></li>
                            <li class="yuimenuitem"><a href="#">SUBMENU2</a></li>
                            <li class="yuimenuitem"><a href="#">SUBMENU3 </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="yuimenuitem"><a href="#">MENU4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the failure continues, it might be because of my browser. Before duplicated submenu appears this: "Submenu expanded submenu Click to collapse.".but still nothing happens by clicking

Comment: DId you check out the example I linked to? This is doing what you want, creating a multi-tier menu using existing markup.